# How do we prove $x^4+1$ divides $x^{12}+x^5+x+1$?

Tags: polynomials

So we have
$$p(x)=x^{12}+x^5+x+1$$
and I thought okay, the only possible rational roots will be $\pm 1$ for all polynomials $p$, but for this one I tried -1 and found it is a root. So, after polynomial division:

$$p(x)=(x+1)q(x)$$
where the degree of $q$ is one less than $p$. Now, looking at $q$, I noticed the signs were plus 5 odd minus 3 even. So I thought that $\pm 1$ would never work since the numbers are not balanced we can't have a root.

And yet my friend told me that $x^4+1$ apparently divides $q$. What would be a good way one would figure that out with pen and paper? Do we need to calculate $q$ specifically or can we possibly see it quicker just from looking at $p$?

Comment: Can you show that  $x^4+1$ divides both $x^5+x$ and $x^{12}+1$? The latter for the same reason that $t+1$ divides $t^3+1$.

Comment: Ahh yes this trick with the cubic polynomials. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do polynomial long division? Seems like the most general and straight-forward route.

Comment: @Snared if you have solved it, you may [answer your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Do not forget to add appropriate acknowledgements in the answer!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could you show how $t+1$ is always a factor of $t^3+1$ please?

Comment: @James, you know how $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$? Well, there's a similar formula for $t^3+1$, which every student ought to learn. Find it!

Comment: $(t+1)(t^2-t+1)=t^3 -t^2 + t + t^2 - t + 1 = t^3+1$ indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Arthur suggested, if in doubt use polynomial division. This amounts to
$$\begin{array}{llll}
(x^{12} + x^5 + x + 1) &\div & (x^4+1) & = x^8 - x^4 + x + 1\\
-(x^{12}+x^8)\\
\hline
-x^8 + x^5 + x + 1\\
-(-x^8 - x^4)\\
\hline
x^5 + x^4 + x + 1\\
-(x^5 + x)\\
\hline
x^4 + 1\\
-(x^4 + 1)\\
\hline
0
\end{array}$$
Note that you may always try @Jyrki Lahtonen's nice trick, since if $p \mid f$ then $p \mid (f+g) \iff p \mid g$. In this specific instance it is quite clear that $(x^4+1) \mid (x^5+x)$, so you only need to check, whether $(x^4 + 1) \mid (x^{12}+1)$. With the substitution $z=x^4$ this amounts to checking $(z+1) \mid (z^3+1)$, which is the same as asking whether $-1$ is a root of $z^3+1$ (which it obviously is).

Comment: $(x^4+1)(x^8-x^4+x+1)=x^{12}-x^8+x^5+x^4+x^8-x^4+x+1=x^{12}+x^5+x+1$ indeed, is there an algorithmic version of this to factorize any polynomial without a prior guess?

Comment: I did not quess $x^8-x^4+x-1$, it is the result of long division in the polynomial ring $Q[x]$... It is basically the same algorithm you use to find out, whether one integer number divides another...

Comment: what if we don't know the divisor candidate $x^4+1$, then there are infinitely many divisors (different coefficients and powers) to test case by case?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question. I am unaware of any general factorization algorithm. For polynomials over a finite field, you may use the sieve of Erastothenes in combination with polynomial division.

Comment: @James Make a substitution $t = x^4$. We get $t^3+tx+x+1 = (t^3+1)+x(t+1) = (t+1)(t^2-t+1)+x(t+1) = (t+1)(t^2-t+x+1) = (x^4+1)(x^8 - x^4+x+1)$

Comment: @James, there are algorithms for testing polynomials for irreducibility, and for factoring the ones that factor, and there is active research into finding improvements. It's all a bit difficult to explain in a short space and at an introductory level. A little websearch for *polynomial factorization* or for *polynomial irreducibility testing* might get you started on what's out there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I wonder suppose we take 4 polynomial keys of order 1000 (or higher), $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$, then publish the product $Q = P_1P_2P_3P_4$. We then give $P_1$ to Alice, $P_2$ to Bob, $P_3$ to Charlie, and leave $P_4$ secret as the true key to the cryptext. For sufficiently intractable polynomial orders, does this make for a shared key where only 3 of them together can factorize $Q$ completely?

Comment: I'm no expert on this, James, but it seems to me it's no different asking about polynomial keys than asking about numerical keys. More to the point, the comment section of one question is not such a good place to ask another question – it's better to post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Computation Of The Quotient**

Noticing the applicability of a few fairly well-known identities, we can compute the quotient.

Since $u^3+1=(u+1)\left(u^2-u+1\right)$, setting $u=x^4$, we get $x^{12}+1=\left(x^4+1\right)\left(x^8-x^4+1\right)$.

Furthermore, $x^5+x=x\left(x^4+1\right)$.

Therefore,
$$
x^{12}+x^5+x+1=\left(x^4+1\right)\left(x^8-x^4+x+1\right)
$$

---

**Scaffold Division**
$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{l}
\phantom{x^4+1\ \ }x^8\ \ -x^4+x\phantom{5}+1\\[-4pt]
x^4+1\enclose{longdiv}{x^{12}\phantom{{}+x^8}+x^5\phantom{{}+x^5}+x+1}\\[-4pt]
\phantom{x^4+1\ \ }\underline{x^{12}+x^8}\\[-2pt]
\phantom{x^4+1\ \ x^{12}}-x^8+x^5\phantom{{}+x^5}+x+1\\[-4pt]
\phantom{x^4+1\ \ x^{12}}\underline{{}-x^8\phantom{{}+x^5\!}-x^4}\\[-2pt]
\phantom{x^4+1\ \ x^{12}-x^8+{}\!}x^5+x^4+x+1\\[-4pt]
\phantom{x^4+1\ \ x^{12}-x^8+{}\!}\underline{x^5\phantom{{}+x^4}+x}\\[-2pt]
\phantom{x^4+1\ \ x^{12}-x^8+x^5+{}\!\!}x^4\phantom{{}+x}+1\\[-4pt]
\phantom{x^4+1\ \ x^{12}-x^8+x^5+{}\!\!}\underline{x^4\phantom{{}+x}+1}\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way

$$x^4+1=0 \implies x_k=e^{i\frac{k\pi}4}\; k=0,1,2,3$$

and

$$p(x_k)= e^{i3k\pi}+e^{i\frac{5k\pi}4}+e^{i\frac{k\pi}4}+1=-1+e^{i\frac{k\pi}4}\left(e^{ik\pi}+1\right)+1=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$p(x)=x^4+1\,$ has no multiple roots because $\,\gcd(p, p')=1\,$ and $\,x^4+1 = 0 \iff x^ 4 = -1\,$, then $\,q(x)=x^{12}+x^5+x+1 = (x^4)^3 + (x^4)\cdot x + x + 1 = -1 -x + x + 1 = 0\,$ so it follows that $\,p(x) \mid q(x)\,$.

Comment: (+1) I just realized that after fixing my first argument, it was the same as yours, so I removed it.